# OS boot menu on Windows XP / Windows Server 2003

Tags: boot

I had Windows XP in C: and Windows Server 2003 on D:, and now I newly installed Windows Vista on my C: drive.

While installing I formatted my entire C: drive so now there is no option to enter into my Windows Server 2003. Is there a possibility to create boot.ini with these multi OSes?

The old Windows Server 2003 is still on my system as D:, but I don't have the option to boot to it. Is there a way to set it up so that I can choose which OS at boot time?

Answer (score 2):

Open C:\boot.ini in Notepad (or edit it via the "system properties") after making it writable, and under the [operating systems] section add:
multi(0)disk(1)rdisk(1)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows 2003" /NoExecute=OptIn /fastdetect

According to the disk number and the partition number of the Windows Server 2003 installation, you might need to change it a little.

Don't forget to set boot.ini to be read-only again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively easy problem to fix - you simply need to edit your `boot.ini` file.

For a Microsoft-certified response on editing your `boot.ini` file (and a much safer way than editing it straight out with notepad!), check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022) link.

Please don't go straight out and edit your `boot.ini`'s contents - it is critically important. If you have no other option, at least make a backup!